# Pickle Is Giving Errors

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to make a RPG style simple game.
I want to save the player location using pickle but i don't know how to create a pickle file and where to create it. Here is a sample code with the error that is coming up:

```
def inp():
    calc=int(input())
import pickle
def saveload(opt):
    global calc
    if opt == "save":
        f = (filename, 'wb')
        pickle.dump(calc, f)
        f.close
        print( 'data saved')
    elif opt == "load":
        f = (filename, 'rb')
        calc = pickle.load(f)
    else:
        print( 'Invalid saveLoad option')
```

The error  is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    saveload('save')
  File "C:/Abhay's Folder/shelve test.py", line 7, in saveload
    f = (filename, 'wb')
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined
```

What is the problem here? Any help will be appreciated.
new programm:

```
import pickle
def inp():
    calc=int(input())
def saveload(filename, opt):
    global calc
    if opt == "save":
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(int(calc),f)
        print('data saved')
    elif opt == "load":
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            calc = pickle.load(f)
    else:
        print('Invalid saveLoad option')
```

new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    saveload('/PythonPickle/windows','save')
  File "C:\Abhay's Folder\shelve test.py", line 8, in saveload
    pickle.dump(int(calc),f)
NameError: name 'calc' is not defined
```

so for some reason, python is not recognizing the variable now.

Comment: The error is self explanatory, in your code filename is a variable and it's is undefined as you never assigned it.

Comment: `filename` should have the path of file where you want to save the pickled data

Comment: you missed to assign the actual file name to the `filename` variable.

Comment: That looks like it should be `f = open(filename, 'wb')`, too - just assigning a tuple to `f` is not going to do you any good.

Comment: so i have to make a file first and then use that file to store the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need `filename` as a parameter to the function.
- You should use `open` to create a file pointer. You are creating a tuple when you assign `f = (filename, 'wb')`.
- Ensure that `calc` is declared and you're using the `global` version of it, in both functions.

```py
import pickle
calc = None
def inp():
    global calc
    calc=int(input())
def saveload(filename, opt):
    global calc
    if opt == "save":
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(calc, f)
        print('data saved')
    elif opt == "load":
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            calc = pickle.load(f)
    else:
        print('Invalid saveLoad option')
saveload('/tmp/calc.pickle', 'save')
```

Comment: in your answer, you have named the file as /tmp/calc.pickle so do i have to create a file with that path first?

Comment: No, as long as you already have a /tmp/ directory (which you would on many OS's), it should work. If you don't, then change it to a different directory. The "wb" flag allows it to write a new file as binary (or overwrite an existing file). Try it out.

Comment: I tried using your code and created a new directory(as the one you used wasnt there). the programm is working but when i try to save the value of the variable, an error is coming up--name calc is not defined. calc has been defined as a global variable already.

Comment: Please update your original question with details - hard to tell by your comment

Comment: i used the shelve module to save the data so now i dont need pickle. do i need to close this question or something?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the other things you need: to use the global `calc` in the `inp()` function, and declare `calc`. As a note for clarity: none of these errors are actually related to `pickle`. You may close it and/or accept the new answer to prevent new answers